# Scope of colormap

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, color-mapping

How is `colormap` scoped in `matlab`? The below example seems to suggest that it is not lexically scoped because the value set within a block of code is accessible outside that block.

```
% example 1
for i=1:3
    colormap('gray');
    subplot(2,2,i);
    imagesc(eye(5));
end
subplot(2,2,4);
imagesc(eye(5));
```

Furthermore, its definition seems to depend upon whether other functions (e.g., `figure`) are called. In the following two examples, `colormap` appears to be dynamically scoped based on whether other functions are called.

```
% example 2
colormap(gray);
for i=1:4
    subplot(2,2,i);
    imagesc(eye(5));
end

% example 3
colormap(gray);
figure;
for i=1:4
    subplot(2,2,i);
    imagesc(eye(5));
end
```

In 'example 2,' the gray color map is applied to each `image`. In 'example 3,' the default `colormap` (`jet`) is used for each `image`, which suggests that calling the function `figure` supersedes previous `colormap` definitions, reseting them to a default value. What other function calls have this property?

Lastly, what is the effect of calling `colormap('default')`? Given my previous assumption that calls to `figure` reset the `colormap` to the default value, the following code does not, as I would expect, produce images with the `gray` `colormap`. Rather, all figures use the `jet` `colormap`. In what sense has the `gray` `colormap` been made a default?

```
% example 4
colormap(gray);
colormap('default');
figure;
for i=1:4
    subplot(2,2,i);
    imagesc(eye(5));
end
```

Answer (score 4):

All relevant graphics objects in the same figure share a colormap.  Each figure maintains a colormap in the `'colormap'` property.  For example: `get(gcf,'colormap')`.

`colormap('NAME')` applies to the current figure.  This has the effect of `set(gcf,'ColorMap',cm)`.

`colormap(axisHandle,..)` or `colormap(figurehandle, ...)` explicitly identify the figure whose colormap is being set.  Note that the `colormap(axisHandle,..)` syntax still sets the colormap of a figure, it just uses the axisHandle's parent property to determine which figure is being set.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Pursuit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908680/97160) explained, a figure has only a single colormap applied by all axes/images contained inside of it. Nonetheless, there are ways to overcome this:

> [How do I use multiple colormaps in a single figure?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-GNRWEH/index.html)

There is also a handy [submission](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/07/24/using-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure/) on the File Exchange:

> [freezeColors / unfreezeColors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943)